# Onclick event target bubbles to child?

Tags: reactjs

I am noticing an issue with onClick defined on a parent div. When user clicks on a child div, the onlick event target is bubbled to the child div, even though there is no onClick defined on it.

The code:

```
function handleClickEvent (event) {
    console.log(event.target.className);  // => "block_flare"
    let new_id = event.target.getAttribute('data-id'); // => null
}


<div className="block" data-id={option.id} onClick={handleClickEvent}>
    <div className="block_content_wrap">
        <div data-id={option.id} className="block_content">{option.name}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="block_flare"></div>
</div>
```

I need to get the `data-id` of the clicked div. One simple solution is to copy the `data-id` to all child divs. Is there a better/different way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.currentTarget` instead ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)). It will give you the element to which the event handler was attached.